# i copied this code from our book but it's not working

Tags: html, css

I copied this code from the book but the CSS isn't working. I hope someone can tell me what I'm missing.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <style type="text/css">
    p.one {
    border-width: 2px;
}
    p.two {
    border-width: thick;
}
    p.three {
    border-width: 1px 4px 12px 4px;
}
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <p class="one">Hohner's "Clavinet" is essentially an electric clavichord.</p>
    <p class="two"> Hohner's "Clavinet" is essentially an electric clavichord.</p>
    <p class="three">Hohner's "Clavinet" is essentially an electric clavichord.</p>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: There is no border-style defined. Add `p { border-style: solid; }`

Comment: Actually it is being applied but since you don't have a `border-color` you cannot see it directly, try to inspect the element in your browser to view the rendered style in the screen.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code is working, but nothing is being displayed because the css properties need to be accompinied by a border color and style property. For example:

```css
p.one {
    border-width: 2px;
    border-color: black;
    border-style: solid;
}
    p.two {
    border-width: thick;
    border-color: black;
    border-style: solid;
}
    p.three {
    border-width: 1px 4px 12px 4px;
    border-color: black;
    border-style: solid;
}
```

```html
<p class="one">Hohner's "Clavinet" is essentially an electric clavichord.</p>
    <p class="two"> Hohner's "Clavinet" is essentially an electric clavichord.</p>
    <p class="three">Hohner's "Clavinet" is essentially an electric clavichord.</p>
```

Here are some helpful links:
https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_border.asp
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/border

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 1):

What you are basically referring to is the [css border proprty](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_border.asp).

You need to put at least 3 configs for it to work. See the example below.

1. The **border-width** property specifies the width of the four borders.
2. The **border-color** property is used to set the color of the four borders.
3. The **border-style** property specifies what kind of border to display.

```css
p {
  border: 1px solid red;
}

p.one {
  border-width: 2px;
}

p.two {
  border-width: thick;
}

p.three {
  border-width: 1px 4px 12px 4px;
}
```

```html
<p class="one">Hohner's "Clavinet" is essentially an electric clavichord.</p>
<p class="two"> Hohner's "Clavinet" is essentially an electric clavichord.</p>
<p class="three">Hohner's "Clavinet" is essentially an electric clavichord.</p>
```

Answer (score 0):

Since css `border-style` default value is `none`, you can't see the border even if you change the border width.

Try to set `border-style` to something like `solid` and you will see the difference.

https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_border-style.asp